# Transition from malloc to New

Tags: c++

I've been working with a tutor on one of my assignments and within they had use me malloc. I am being told by my instructor that I should use new instead. In order to transition between the two, I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

What I had (couple of examples);

```
char* songTitle = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);

songTitle = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);

title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
```

What I hope is correct on the transition;

```
char* songTitle = new char[50];

songTitle = new char[50];

title = new char [50];
```

An example snippets of what I'm using;

Snippet #1

```
cin.ignore();
cout << "What is the title of the song? " << endl;
char* songTitle = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
cin.getline(songTitle, 50);
songTitle[0] = std::toupper(songTitle[0]);

for (std::size_t i = 1; i < strlen(songTitle); ++i)
    songTitle[i] = std::tolower(songTitle[i]);
```

Snippet #2

```
cin.ignore();
cout << "What is the title of the song? " << endl;
songTitle = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
cin.getline(songTitle, 50);
songTitle[0] = std::toupper(songTitle[0]);
```

Snippet #3

```
while (true && count < ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
        artist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
        duration = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
        album = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);

        inFile.getline(title, 50, '\|');
        songs[count].setTitle(title);
        inFile.getline(artist, 50, '\|');
        songs[count].setArtist(artist);
        inFile.getline(duration, 50, '\|');
        songs[count].setDuration(duration);
        inFile.getline(album, 50, '\|');
        songs[count].setAlbum(album);

        if (inFile.eof() == true)
            break;

        count++;
    }
```

Comment: Assuming all variables are of type `char*` and you add semicolons, yes that appears correct.

Comment: Really, you should transition direct to using `std::string`, rather than use `char *` with `new`.  That resolves your memory leak problems almost automatically — well, if you're a bit careful.  Using `new` is a low-level programming thing, generally to be avoided.  Assuming that the initialization of `songTitle` is not followed by the assignment to `songTitle`, you're more or less correct, though leaky.  You need to work out where the memory is freed. The initialization and assignment definitively leak memory if there is no `delete[] songTitle;` between the two operations.

Comment: `if ( inFile.eof() == true )` should be `if ( !inFile )`

Comment: Prefer `std::string`, and also, missing `delete[]` in all of your code snippets.

Comment: As has been said, that looks correct - assuming that you will never set<Value> to any string longer than your allocated 50 characters including the NUL. For your understanding however, the main difference between malloc and new is for arrays of an object that has a constructor and/or destructor. malloc and free will not call these for you, whereas new and delete will. It doesn't matter for _char_, but it's good to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you all and I would love to use string, however I am only allowed to use only cstring.

Answer (score 0):

OP has stated that they are stuck with char arrays. This is unfortunate, but in all of the above cases there seems to be no need for any dynamic allocation at all. To abuse an old Gung-fu teaching about the escalating levels of harm, local before new. New before malloc.

Local variables self-destruct when they pass out of [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). You cannot return one from a function, for example, because they are destroyed when the unction ends. But you never have to worry about the clean up. You know exactly when it was created and exactly when it will be destroyed.

To use a local variable, you need to know how big it is ad how long it will be around. When you don't know one or both, move on to the next in the hierarchy: `new`

`new` incurs greater risk than a local allocation. Anything `new`ed must be released with `delete` when it is no longer required. This is extra book-keeping in the hands of the programmer, and may have been forgotten or not covered in all possible flows of the code. This is called a memory leak. `new` also provides a memory allocation of exactly the right size and calls the constructors of complex objects, ensuring that they are properly initialized.

`malloc` has about the same level of leakage risk as `new`, but `malloc` requires the programmer specify the correct sizing, opening up the possibility for typos and oyher human errors. It cannot be used to crate a complex data type. It provides raw memory but does not call any construction logic. It's counterpoint, `free` only put memory back. No destructors are called.

For songtitle, `malloc` can be used because `char` is a simple datatype, but requires extra math to get the sizing right and casting to force the datatype. Extra risk. `new` eliminates the possibility of casting and sizing errors, but still requires manual memory management. The size of the array is known so the first requirement of using a local variable is met. The lifespan of the variable is not known.

if `setTitle` is assigning `songtitle` to a member variable, the lifespan is extended and

```
char* songTitle = new char[50];
```

is probably the best option. If `setTile` copies `songtitle` into a member variable the lifespan is known and short. In that case, go with a local variable:

```
char songTitle[50];
```